# crawl unlimited field into csv file

Tags: python, scrapy, web-crawler

i wanna crawl a website with unknown number of field and i want to export as a csv file like this:

this is the data i want to crawl
[image]

and this is the csv file that i want to export:

[image]

now my code is like this and i have problem with that

```
name = "products"

start_urls = [
    'https://www.parchem.com/chemical-supplier-distributor/Acetaldehyde-003316.aspx',
   
]

def parse(self, response):
    
    for products in response.css('div.prd-des-lis'):
        yield{
            products.css('div.prod-categorty p::text').get():products.css('div.prod-category-back p::text').get()
```

and it's the sample source code of the html file

```
 <div class="prd-des-lis">
                    <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 prod-categorty">
                                <p>PRODUCT</p>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-lg-8 col-md-8 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 clearfix prod-categorty prod-category-back">
                                <p>
                                    Acetaldehyde
                                </p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

can someone help me?

Comment: Please post a short HTML sample of what you are trying to parse, rather than linking to a external resource

Comment: i added the sample codes to the post

Comment: So basically you want to flip the rows and columns in your output right?

Comment: yes exactly i want that

Comment: Can you please include the code where you write the csv file?

Comment: i just use 'scrapy crawl products -o prod.csv -t csv' into terminal to export file

Comment: "i have problem with that" -- can you be more specific? Does it give an error (and if so, what is the literal error message and line number)?

Comment: no I dont have any error. but the exported file included "" in all rows and It doesn't have field name

Comment: you didn't know how should I solve that?